# How to disable the PIP mode settings icon when the application goes in PIP mode?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to make one kiosk /COSU mode application but using the pip settings button,user can go out of the application. I am building the application for Android Oreo. Please help

Comment: Have you found any solutions yet?